# Linking schema in Apollor server 2

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a case that I'm not sure to implement, I have a REST API that returns an array of user IDs. Like this:

```
{
   status: ""
   "users": [
   {
            "userId": ID
   },
   {
            "userId": ID
   }
   ]
}
```

I want to have the ability to get the user details for each userID, so I want to pass the ID to another API that gets the user details.

The issue is that the second API returns the information as follows

```
{
    status: ""
    data:[{
        Info:{
        userId:
        name:
        ...
        }
        Permissions{
            ...
        }
        ...
    }]
}
```

My issue is how can I represent this relation in the schema?

This is the schema I came up with:

```
Query{
    EventUsersSummary(eventId: ID): EventResponse!
}

type EventResponse{
    status: String!
    users: [EventUser!]!
}

type EventUser {
    userId: ID!
}

type User {
 info: Info
 permissions: Permissions
 ....
}

type Info{
    userId: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: Email
}
....
```

In the resolver for EventResponse I'm removing status from the result. In the resolver I plan to return the information for each user.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Your schema should be driven primarily by the needs of whoever will be consuming your API. The shape of the User type shouldn't depend on the shape of the response from whatever REST API you're calling.

Comment: @DanielRearden My requirement is to get all the users info in an event